# Linq queries on dB and using custom Comparers

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql, linq-to-nhibernate

Whats the use of using custom comparers in Linq queries? Are they beneficial or are they just an overload on the server.

So i am talking about queries like

```
IEnumerable<Class> GetMatch(Class comparerObject)
{
  return  Session.Linq<Class>().Where(x=>new StringComparer<Class>().Equals(x,comparerObject))
}
```

and this is how my stringcomparer class looks like

```
public class StringComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : class, IStringIdentifiable
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

So I was wondering how is this query run against the db? I think  linq handles this internally where in it sends a request to the db only after all the cases in the comparere are run.

Edit:

Well if you are finding it hard to believe that the above will not work then take a simple example like

```
return  Session.Linq<Class>().Where(x=>x.Id.Equals(comparerObject,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Then what do you think is the expected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LINQ to SQL, I'd expect that to fail at execution time - the query translator won't know what to do with your `StringComparer<T>` class.

In the case you've given, you should just use:

```
string idToMatch = comparerObject.Id;
return Session.Linq<Class>().Where(x => x.Id == idToMatch);
```

More complicated cases may or may not be feasible depending on *exactly* what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was under the impression that if Linq doesn't know how to translate a given piece of code into SQL it'll just pull all the data without that condition and apply it on the in-memory collection instead of failing at execution time?  Or am I thinking of something unrelated?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: You can make it do that if you want by calling AsEnumerable, but it won't do it by default.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, will have to remember IQueryable doesn't like things it can't translate.